# Having issue defining go_remote_library declaration for 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text:*

Tags: go, pants

I'm trying to used github.com/spf13/viper which requires github.com/spf13/afero and that requires some of the 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text: packages. Till afero works, and when defining 3rdparty BUILD for text:* packages I get the following errors,

```
3rdparty/go/github.com/spf13/afero has remote dependencies which require local declaration:
        --> golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm (expected go_remote_library declaration at 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text:unicode/norm)
        --> golang.org/x/text/transform (expected go_remote_library declaration at 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text:transform)
```

I tried to define it like this in 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text/BUILD,

```
go_remote_library(
    rev='342b2e1fbaa52c93f31447ad2c6abc048c63e475',
    packages=[
        'unicode/norm',
        'transform',
    ]
)
```

And it still shows the same error. Plus now running buildgen.go fails with the following error,

```
Exception caught: (pants.build_graph.target.UnknownArgumentError) (backtrace omitted)
Exception message: Invalid target 3rdparty/go/golang.org/x/text:text: GoRemoteLibrary received unknown arguments:
    packages = ['unicode/norm', 'transform']
```

Some more info,
- Pants version: 1.13.0
- pantsbuild.pants.contrib.go: 1.13.0
- Tried using 1.14.0 & 1.15.0 as well and got the same results

Simple example to recreate it,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func main() {
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
    fmt.Printf("%s", viper.GetString("HOME"))
}
```

Also you can simply do pants resolve on the package to get the error,

```
pants resolve 3rdparty/go/github.com/spf13/viper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pants team, got the issue resolved.

buildgen.go does turn `go_remote_library(pkg='foo')` takes into go_remote_libraries targets.
We need to use `go_remote_libraries` (not go_remote_library) to specify multiple packages.

Using this works fine,

```
go_remote_libraries(
  rev='342b2e1fbaa52c93f31447ad2c6abc048c63e475',
  packages=[
    'transform',
    'unicode/norm',
  ]
)
```